# How do I change polygon opacity using a esri WFS in leaflet?

Tags: arcgis-server, leaflet, wfs

Note...Solved and here for anyone having this problem...damn simple problem, I had not used a higher case character for fillcolor and fillopacity....they should be fillColor and fillOpacity  , it works after changing that.  mmm

I seem to be able to change the opacity of the polygon outline but not the fill itself.  Can find what is going wrong with my code.  I try to use the fillcolor and fillopacity but nothing changes on my map?

```
var LMDB1 = new L.FeatureGroup();

    L.esri.featureLayer("https://services.arcgis.com/HIDDEN/arcgis/rest/services/HIDDEN/FeatureServer/1", {

        style: function (feature) {
        if(feature.properties.TAG === 'Lowest Health'){
            return { color: "#AD0909", weight: 1, opacity: .1, fillcolor: "#000000", fillopacity: 1};
            } else if(feature.properties.TAG === 'Low to Average Health'){
            return { color: "#FF8000", weight: 1, opacity: .1 };
            } else if(feature.properties.TAG === 'Average Health'){
            return { color: "#FFFB0D", weight: 1, opacity: 1 };
            } else if(feature.properties.TAG === 'Average to High Health'){
            return { color: "#C4FFD3", weight: 1, opacity: 1 };
            } else if(feature.properties.TAG === 'Highest Health'){
            return { color: "#0E8F2E", weight: 1, opacity: 1 };
            } else {
            return { color: "#FFFFFF", weight: 1, opacity: 1 };
            }
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(poly_templ, feature.properties));}

        }).addTo(LMDB1);
```